# How to sandbox js code in an iframe with same origin?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

If I have a page `A` from origin `O`, and it has an iframe with a page `B` also from origin `O`, and `B` has js code. Normally, since its same origin, the js code in the iframe can use `.parent()` and access the outside page, but is there a way from `A`, to pass data to the js of `B`, and then change the origin of `B` to something else such that `B` cannot access the parent page `A` anymore?

Thanks

Comment: Use the `sandbox` attribute of `<iframe>`

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/